# can't see Page2,3,.. when i set GridView paging to true

Tags: asp.net

I set `AllowPaging` of Gridview to True,when records more than one page i can see page's number (1,2,..) but when i click on number can't see other pages (Page2,3 ,...)  and page doesn't change

i use `DataBind()` in `PageIndexChanging` event but when i click on number i can't see GridView

Comment: Show your aspx markup. Are you using declarative datasources like `SqlDataSource` or manual like `DataTable`? If the latter, don't bind the `GridView` in `page_load` to it's DataSource if `Page.IsPostback`.

Comment: i use dataTable and set it to GridView manually in PageLoad but check `if(! IsPostBack)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sufficient to call `GridView.DataBind()`. You also have to set the new [`PageIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindex.aspx) in [`PageIndexChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    // now get the DataSource(f.e. from database) and assign it
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Also note that you should not bind the DataSource to the GridView in [`Page_Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.load%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on postbacks, instead always check the `IsPostback` property:

If the latter, don't bind the `GridView` in `page_load` to it's DataSource if Page.IsPostback.

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
         BindGridView(); // assuming this is the method where you databind the grid
    }
}
```

Comment: with this way gridview's page change but i can't see any row in second page(actually GridView is hidden)

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad: That doesn't sound exceptional: _"i can't see any row in second page, actually GridView is hidden"_. Is it desired that the GridView is hidden? You need to call `BindGridView` (or similar method where you databind the grid) from `PageIndexChanging`.

Comment: when i click on number 2 (Page 2) i can't see any row in GridView

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad: Have you seen [what i've edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12798704/revisions)? You need to change the `PageIndex`, assign the datasource to the GridView(probably selecting from database) and finally call `GridView.DataBind()`. Have you done that?

Comment: Tim: I am facing the same problem, and I also cant see the page 2,3

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call Databind in PageIndexChanging, you will need to set the GridViews PageIndex like so

```
void GrdView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView x = ((GridView)sender);

        if (e.NewPageIndex > -1 && e.NewPageIndex <= x.PageCount)
        {
            x.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        }

        GrdView.DataBind();
    }
```